# Does convex functios $f$ always achieves a minimum on closed convex sets whenever the $f$ have an unconstrained minimum?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that achieves minimum at some point of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I want to know if the problem \begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c c}
\text{minimize}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}  & f(x) \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{aligned}
      x \in \Omega,\\ 
     \end{aligned} 
\end{array}
\end{equation*} with $\Omega$ closed and convex, have a solution. Does it have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no. Consider the counter-example in which $\Omega$ is the (unbounded) first-quadrant hyperbolic region $xy\geq 1$ and let $f(x,y)=|y|$, which is convex and has its minimum attained on the  $x$ axis. The restriction of $f$ to $\Omega$ has no attained minimum.

Comment: And If $\Omega$ is a vector space?

Comment: What if the function $f$ is strictly convex?

Comment: When a convex function is strictly convex, it is coercive. When a function is coercive, such a function achieves minimum over any closed domain, and not only convex domain, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240269/coercive-continuous-function-on-a-closed-subset-has-a-global-minimum-proof